# Using Breeze with an ODBC Connection

Tags: odbc, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I am in the beginning stages of writing an angularjs client that talks to a RESTful ASP.net Web Api server and am trying to integrate Breeze.  I have full control over both client and server code, but the one non-negotiable is that I have to connect to a DBISAM database that I'm sharing with a legacy Windows desktop app; so I can not take advantage of the Entity Framework that most Breeze Server examples use.  I've successfully retrieved data by setting up a controller similar to the one in the NoDB example and am now trying to figure out the best way to get real data from my database.  Also, I am able to get data from the DB using the ODBC connection, but I'm just not sure where that will fit in with the Breeze way of doing things.

Given all of that, here are my specific questions:

- are there any Breeze Server examples showing how to retrieve/save data using a database connected via ODBC that I have somehow overlooked?
- will I need to create an adapter to make this work?  And if so, is the mongodb adapter the closest thing to use as an example of what that code should look like?
- Without Entity Framework, is it still better to return the metadata from the server, or should I create it on the client instead?
- I understood the documentation to say that it is easier to have the server be Breeze "aware", but is that still true when needing to use ODBC?  Perhaps I should just use Breeze on the client side instead, similar to the Edmunds example?

thanks for any help with figuring out the best way to proceed!

Comment: Hmm, given the lack of a response from a Breeze person, I guess I should assume that it would be too hard to do what I'm trying to do with Breeze?